# Merging tags facebook-page, facebook-fanpage and fan-page

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [facebook-fanpage](/questions/tagged/facebook-fanpage) (332) and [fan-page](/questions/tagged/fan-page) (63) seems to be being used to ask questions about a single thing, i.e. Facebook pages. Should they be merged?

And are they really needed when [facebook-page](/questions/tagged/facebook-page) (623) is already there?

A [*Facebook Page*](https://www.facebook.com/help/281592001947683/) is defined as -

> Pages are for businesses, organizations and brands to share their
> stories and connect with people. Like Timelines, you can customize
> Pages by posting stories, hosting events, adding apps and more. Engage
> and grow your audience by posting regularly. People who like your Page
> and their friends can get updates in News Feed.
>
> You can create and manage a Facebook Page from your personal account.

There is nothing called a *Fan Page* in case of Facebook. There is just *Page*.

Comment: If used correctly, they do signify different things. Facebook is not the only one providing fan pages and the handling of a fanpage in facebook is different than the handling of normal facebook pages.

Comment: @ThunderGr what's the difference between a normal facebook page and a facebook fanpage?

Comment: A fanpage is attached to a normal page and you are given tools to customize it in different ways than a normal page. In addition, you define administrators for the fanpage, you get statistics etc etc

Comment: @ThunderGr can you show a reference to that? Because AFAIK Facebook has just one entity called Page. There is nothing called "Fan page" officially.

Comment: http://socialmediatoday.com/stephaniefrasco/1446966/15-benefits-having-fan-page-over-personal-page-facebook

Comment: @ThunderGr Umm. In that article, what they are calling a "personal page" is the Facebook Profile. and the "Fan page" they refer to is a Facebook Page. A user with Single profile, can create multiple "Pages". A profile is just the details webpage for a user.

Comment: "Personal Page" is the actual facebook page you have, that has your wall. If you want tabs, statistics, administrators etc, you need a fan page. You cannot have tabs in your Personal page. And there are no likes there. It so happens that I have a personal page and that I have created fan pages for others. They are different.

Comment: @ThunderGr what you're calling a "Personal page" is what I'm calling a profile. And what I'm calling a "Facebook page" is what Facebook calls their pages https://www.facebook.com/help/281592001947683/. There is nothing called a personal page. "Page" is an entity you create to promote something. See the bottom of that link, there is a link "Learn about converting your personal account to a Facebook Page". That should tell you something.

Comment: Updated the answer with definition of Facebook page.

Comment: Fair enough. It is just a terminology issue, then. So, if there is a tag 'facebook-profile' as opposed to 'facebook-page' then it is OK. However, if by 'facebook-page' we mean what most people mean(what you call 'the profile') then they do different things and should be left separate.

Comment: On a side note, facebook used to call that 'a fan page' but they changed it, at some point. People have not forgotten, though.

Comment: can you also help me with same issue?
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357837/get-a-facebook-page-which-was-on-my-other-account